# How to get method instance in component after @testing-library/react-native render

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-native-testing-library

`SplashScreen` is a React Native 0.70 component. `generatePrivateKey`.After rendering the component `SplashScreen` in `jest 0.29`, how to get the instance of method `generatePrivateKey` for further testing? The code below does not work

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { render, cleanup, screen, fireEvent, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react-native";
import SplashScreen from './SplashScreen';

describe ('Splash screen when launching the app' , () => {
    test ('generate private key method shall work', () => {
        const navigation = () => {
            return {navigate:jest.fn()}
        };

        const component = ( <NavigationContainer>
                                <SplashScreen navigation={navigation}  />
                            </NavigationContainer>);

        const wrapper = render(component);
        const inst = screen.instance.generatePrivatekey();  //NOT working. generatePrivateKey is a method to be tested
        //const inst = wrapper.getByType(SplashScreen).instance.generatePrivateKey() //NOT working
        expect(inst).toBeCalledOnce();
    });

})
```

UPDATE:

Here is the view of the SplashScreen. Method `generatePrivateKey` is activated by user's click.

```
return (
    
    <View style={styles.viewStyles}>
      <Text h1 style={styles.textHeader}>Splash Screen</Text>
      <Image 
        source={imageFile}
        style={{ width:200,height:250 }}
      />
      <Spinner
          visible={spinner}
          textContent={message}
          textStyle={styles.spinnerTextStyle}
      />
      <View style={{width:"80%" }}>
        <Modal
              style={{alignItems:"center", alignContent:"center"}}
              animationType="slide"
              transparent={false}
              visible={modalVisible}
              onBackdropPress={() => setModalVisible(false)}
              onRequestClose={() => {
                setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
              }}
            > 
          <View style={[styles.centeredView, styles.modalView]}>     
              <Text style={{padding:20}}>{keyHint}</Text>
              <TextInput autoFocus={true} editable={!disableKeyInput} value={privateKey} onChangeText={keyChange} placeholder={keyPlaceholder} style={styles.textTitle} />             
              {genPrivKey ? <Button style={styles.button} 
                        onPress={generatePrivatekey} 
                        title={"生成(新)密钥"}/> :
                  <Button style={styles.button} 
                  onPress={savePrivateKey} 
                  title={"保存"}/> 
              }                                     
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </View>  
    </View>
    
  );
```

Comment: How does the `generatePrivatekey` function be called in your component? Show the code.

Comment: `generatePrivateKey` is activated by users' click in view.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in the wrong way.

1. You can't access methods of the functional component.
2. To do it correctly you have to fire press event (see [user-events](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro) lib) on the button that triggers `generatePrivatekey` func and check whether something inside its body has been called